# Toast message, which activity is accurate now

Tags: android, android-studio, toast, android-toast

I made a transition between the windows, but my task is to show the message Toast, Which window is currently being used. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.example);

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

you can call the toast in the `onCreate` of the view

Answer (score 0):

if you need to display the name of current activity class try this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.example);

    Toast.makeText(this, ""+this.getClass().getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```